# Trouble Updating to CrossOver 13.1

Tags: crossover

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I have CrossOver 12.5. According to codeweavers.com I can update to v.13.1.2. I followed the instructions given on the website but it won't install. Is there a step I am missing or a way to update to v.13.1.2 by using the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with CodeWeavers and reading several buried articles online I determined that I could not upgrade CrossOver with Ubuntu 12.04 without removing the current installer program and replacing it which would have apparently prevented me from using the software center and the update service. If you have 12,04 you'll have to stick with the trial version of CrossOver from the software center until Code Weavers fixes this.